# Тестирование поворота экрана

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, test-automation, robolectric

Как можно написать тест на поворот активити?
В общем случае было бы замечательно протестировать пересоздание активити при любой смене конфигрурации.
Вообще идеально, если это можно сделать в robolectric.

Мне надо протестировать корректное поведение retain-фрагмента. Если вызывать в роболектрике `activity.recreate()` то там фрагмент тоже пересоздается, что не есть правда, в моем случае.

Если сделать так:

```
activity.baseContext.resources.updateConfiguration(newConfig, activity.resources.displayMetrics)
```

То вроде бы и работает, как я ожидаю, но одолевают сомнения, что это отрабатывает именно так, как и будет в реальной жизни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем нашел я способ. В роболектрике врятли такое получится.
Пришлось использовать эспрессо и добавить туда UIAutomator.
Все просто делается.
Инициализируем его

> device =
>   UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

и в нужные моменты вызываем

> ```
>     device.setOrientationLeft()
>     device.waitForWindowUpdate(basePackage, 5000)
> ```

basePackage - это пакет, в котором находится ваша активити.
Собственно до вызова, будет одна ориентация, после вызова - другая.

Answer (score 1):

`...но одолевают сомнения, что это отрабатывает именно так, как и будет в реальной жизни.`
Стоит помнить, что Robolectric не обеспечивает 100% имитацию среды Android. И в любом случае, это не будет происходить также как произошло бы в реальности. С большой долей сходства - да, но не полностью. Для таких вещей лучше использовать предназначенные для них фреймворки, как `UiAutomator` или `Espresso`.

Если стоит задача использовать именно Robolectric, то это можно сделать хаком, имитируя жизненные циклы, которые проходят при повороте экрана. 
А он такой

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

А сделать это можно так:

```
    ActivityController<MainActivity> controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
    activity = controller.pause()
            .stop()
            .destroy()
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume().get();
```

Код не тестил, но работать должен.

Так что отвечая на ваш вопрос, эмулировать поворот экрана с помощью `Robolectric` можно. Вопрос, рационально ли?

Comment: роболектрик не подходошел для моих целей, мне нужно было оттестировать на реальном повороте :)